# Generating a IES file from an illuminaire and a lens

Tags: optics, simulation

I have a IES luminaire file of a lamp and some polar candela distribution plots of lenses like:
[image]

How can I create a new luminaire file combining the lamp with every lens?

I could manually sample the plots in order to retrieve the information from the plot but I haven't been able to fully understand how to weight the candelas values from the IES using the lens plots. I assume the plots are representing the iluminare of an ideal candela through a lens, but I'm not sure. Even if I were correct, there's various distributions (ways to weight each candela value of an IES) that for an ideal candela will output that plot.